# recurring delayed jobs in rails / heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

How do I dynamically create and run recurring delayed jobs at runtime in rails/heroku and delete them as needed ? Is there a good gem for this?

I would like to be able to schedule a delayed job at a configurable frequency from runtime depending on user choice. Is there a gem that could help me achieve this? This is specifically to schedule recurring payments at a specific frequency and with a start and end date so I need to able to retrieve the delayed jobs and deactivate them. Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for gem named as **whenever** . It has very good documentation and i think it will help you in what you are looking for . Here is the link https://github.com/javan/whenever .

Answer (score 1):

There is at least two good solutions that you could use for this:

1. The **Heroku Scheduler** (https://elements.heroku.com/addons/scheduler).
2. **Clockwork Gem** (https://github.com/Rykian/clockwork). On Heroku 
   you would spin this up as a separate dyno.

*I suggest that you only add jobs to a background worker queue using e.g. Sidekiq, Delayed::Job or SuckerPunch. The reason being that you don't want your scheduler to freeze as your tasks will waste CPU cycles and RAM.*